# Как правильно реализовать бесконечный цикл в windows службе. c#

Tags: c#, windows-service

у меня возникла проблема при запуске службы.

> Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно

Код программы:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        while (true)
        {
            //Тут используется именованный канал, для моих нужд. 
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        logger.Info("Запуск");
    }
```

Причину ошибки понял, дело в том, что служба не запускается из-за бесконечного цикла. Но, что делать если в программе у меня требуется бесконечный цикл и без него не обойтись. Как правильно реализовать бесконечный цикл, чтобы служба запустилась?

Comment: цикл надо убрать, из-за него метод `onStart` не завершается. вместо цикла моджно сделать через таймер и метод OnTimerTick

Comment: какую операцию вы выполняете в цикле?

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно, зачем нужен бесконечный цикл? Если надо выполнить функцию,  спустя какое то время, то можно сделать это через таймер как написал @Ruslan_K . Или можно выполнять этот цикл пока. допустим. ваша функция не вернет false или true. Для этого сделайте чтоб ваша функция возвращала bool значение : while (boolvalue == true) { boolvalue = somefunction(); Thread.Sleep(500); }

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Сделаю через таймер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример я решил написать тут(для более понятного ответа):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        bool boolvalue = true; 
        while (boolvalue == true)
        {
            boolvalue = YourFunction ();
            //Тут используется именованный канал, для моих нужд. 
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        logger.Info("Запуск");
    }
    bool YourFunction () {
     if(...)
     {
      return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
  }
```

В этом варианте не будет ошибки 1053. И цикл когда то завершиться, когда ваша функция вернёт false.